# Adding an exit on gRPC request in Gatling

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

I have a bidiStream configured as below

```
.exec(
    bidiStream_conf
      .start("#{payload}")
      .header(metadataObject.Authorization)(s"Bearer ${Key}")
      .extract(_.pk.some)(_ saveAs "var")
      .sessionCombiner(SessionCombiner.pick("var"))
      .endCheck(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
  )
.exitHereIfFailed
.exec(REST_req)
.exec(bidiStream_conf.complete)
.exec(bidiStream_conf.reconciliate(waitFor = NextMessage))
```

I want to force exit on V.User when stream is failed, so I passed in a false key, when I run this, I got below log

```
gRPC stream completion:
status=
PERMISSION_DENIED, description: code = E3014, message = Token is invalid!
trailers=
content-type: application/grpc
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
15:45:32.700 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.s.BidiStreamCall - Client issued message but stream bidiStream_conf already completed

================================================================================
2023-11-30 15:45:34                                           5s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=2      KO=1     )
> bidiStream_Req                                           (OK=0      KO=1     )
> REST_Req                                                 (OK=1      KO=0     )
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> grpcStatusCode.find.is(OK), but actually found PERMISSION_DENI      1 (100.0%)
ED
```

Seeing that REST API below is still executed, I think I did `exitHereIfFailed` wrong way, how do I properly do that in this case, to force V.User to stop whole scenario completely ?

Answer (score 0):

To force an exit of the whole scenario when the gRPC stream fails, you can use Gatling's `exitBlockOnFail` method.

Check this code:

```
.exec(
  bidiStream_conf
    .start("#{payload}")
    .header(metadataObject.Authorization)(s"Bearer ${Key}")
    .extract(_.pk.some)(_ saveAs "var")
    .sessionCombiner(SessionCombiner.pick("var"))
    .endCheck(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
 )
.exitHereIfFailed // Remove this line
.exitBlockOnFail( // Add this block
    exec(REST_req),
    exec(bidiStream_conf.complete),
    exec(bidiStream_conf.reconciliate(waitFor = NextMessage))
 )
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for helping me, could you explain more what will happen in exitBlockOnFail so that I can have a clear understand about this code ?

Comment: @TriNguyen                                                                                                                
The exitBlockOnFail block contains three actions:

exec(REST_req): Executes the REST_req action.
exec(bidiStream_conf.complete): Executes the bidiStream_conf.complete action.
exec(bidiStream_conf.reconciliate(waitFor = NextMessage)): Executes the bidiStream_conf.reconciliate action with a specific parameter.
If any of these actions fail, the entire Gatling scenario will be terminated, and the simulation will exit.

Comment: Hi, it seems that your code doesn't match my need because the block will still have to execute REST_req, what I need is to avoid REST_req to be executed, it's a different use case